# encrypted voip traffic for voip provider that doesn't offer encryption

Tags: encryption, proxy, voip

I currently use a VoIP service with one VoIP provider. However, this company doesn't offer encryption to VoIP traffic. This mean that all voice transmit via my IPphone can be sniffed and listen. (I already tested that). I try to enable SRTP in my IPphone but then the server rejected it which indicated that the company doesn't support it.

Is there anyway I can setup a proxy server or something similar that encrypts the VoIP data then forward the data to my VoIP provider? The other end will have the same set up so that the proxy server will decrypt it and send it to the phone. Or is there any IPphone that can encrypt the traffic before sending it to SIP server?

Comment: Does the other party use VOIP or PSTN?

Comment: Both party are VoIP